# Improve Serial port on Windows 10

Tags: windows, serial-port

I have a data buffer of data on my Serial port. This communication is developed in order to transfer the "maximum" value of possible data. Hence, the value of samples "send" if there is no connection with a computer is around ~11500 data/sec. If I attach the controller (who send the data) on a Windows 10 machine and I try to read (with java) the data, the information frequency drops down to ~ 950/1000 data/sec. Otherwise, if I attach the controller to the same machine, with the same software, but under Ubuntu, it reaches ~6000/7000 data/sec. So, there is a way to improve the Serial port under Windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a cheap USB-serial port, it is possible it only works at USB1 speeds, and/or the driver is basically a rebadged device driver demo from the Windows SDK (which is very poor).  More expensive USB ports generally have their own drivers which are much better at higher data rates.

It is also possible that there is some sort of hardware flow control that isn't quite as efficient on Windows as it is on Linux.

Without knowing exactly which USB port you have, it's difficult to make suggestions.

Comment: You mean the hardware installed on the PC or the serial of the controller?The controller is an Arduino Due, while the computer USB should be ASMedia USB 3.1 (see https://ibb.co/cZdnak )

Comment: I'm confused here, is this serial as in RS232 or serial as in USB (Universal Serial Bus)?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. It is a USB used as serial.